# java.lang.NullPointerException directly after initialising the object using findViewById

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crash

This is a strange crash because the app is tested and found to be running smoothly **(Without any Errors)** on 5-6 Android testing phones, but the Play store is reporting a crash in around 2% of the sessions, which is too high (max accepted by google is 1.09%).

NullPointerException occurs in many places of the app without any logical reasons as all objects are declared at the class level and have been initialised at the beginning of onCreate:

This is just one example of many:

```
btn_display_mode = findViewById(R.id.btn_display_mode);

.
.
(some code in the same class_
.
.
btn_display_mode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    <---- java.lang.NullPointerException
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        updateDisplayMode(displayMode);
    }
});
```

And here another place for the same error:

```
       mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
       adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
       mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);                    <---- java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Do you have alternate layout files that are missing the view or have different view ids?

Comment: Thanks so much Greg, your answer helped me a lot, I will explain how it helped in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

please try like this :

`btn_display_mode = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_display_mode);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Greg..

The reasons for the problem were because i decided to make the app run in portrait orientation only and added the following lines to "onResume" not to "onCreate"

```
       //--------------------- USE FULL SCREEN & KEEP SCREEN ON ------------------------
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = this.getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
```

at the same time there was an abundant landscape Layout called "activity_main (Land)" which I didn't delete and it was not containing all objects contained in "activity_main".

my mistake was putting these 2 lines of code at the beginning of "onResume" & not at the beginning of "onCreate", so when the app starts in Landscape mode it will crash because it will not find all objects in "activity_main (Land)